# Can't see and use custom VCL style

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle

I created a new style in the `Bitmap Style Designer`, saved it in the `Styles` folder, but I can't see it in the project options under the `Appearances` tab. What's wrong?

---

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Check which _internal_ name are you using for your _VCL Style_, this name must be unique.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use an Embarcadero supplyed style as basis, you need to change `Author` and `Name` fields in the designers `Inspector` window.

[image]

Then your style will be listed in Project Options - Appearance under an own divider line:

[image]